# What is the notation for the empty matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

**My question:** What is a notation for an empty 0x0 matrix (i.e. the matrix for the only linear map $f:\{0\}\to\{0\}$)? Is it written $()$? How can I distinguish the 0x0 matrix with for example the 0x3 matrix or the 3x0 matrix?

**What I have already found out:** Concerning the section [“Empty matrices”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29#Empty_matrices) of the Wikipedia article “Matrix (mathematics)” there “is no common notation for empty matrices”. But unfortunately I haven't found any notation so far...

**Notes:** I am looking for a notation which is used in a textbook. I am not interested in how empty matrices can be created in [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) like Matlab, Mathematica, etc.

**Reason for this question:** In our course we had the task to draw all graphs with three vertices and to state the [incidence matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix) for each drawn graph. Thus, for the empty graph I have to state a 0x3 matrix, but I didn't know the right notation for it...

Comment: You could call it $\mathrm{Id}_0$, to represent the $0 \times 0$ identity matrix.

Comment: I like the notation $[]$, the "matrix with nothing in it"

Comment: Just curious: Is there a mathematical reason you're looking to denote the $0 \times 0$ matrix?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: No, actually the reason for asking this question was how I can notate the empty 0x3 matrix. I will add my question with an explanation why I asked the question...

Comment: For a graph on $n$ vertices, the incidence matrix is $n \times n$, and the $(i, j)$-entry is the number of edges from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$. For the empty (i.e., edgeless) graph on three vertices, an existing matrix suits your needs. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any universally recognizable notation for this. Whatever choice one might make, without explanation it could easily be misunderstood, is the point.

(For that matter, I can't help wondering how/why the *notation* would be needed in a context that wouldn't permit the simpler explanation "unique linear map from $k^0$ to $k^0$".)

Answer (score 3):

I think the most simple notation would be to write $$ 0_{M_{0,0}}$$ for a matrix of size $0\times 0$, and $$ 0_{M_{3,0}}$$ for a matrix of size $3\times 0$.

It's very similar when you want to write the zero of an unknown field $F$, when you write $0_F$.